# Python Threading Parameters Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, parameters, parallel-processing

I've been trying for around half an hour now and just cant seem to wrap my head around what im doing wrong here. 
Working Code:

```
import threading
from time import sleep


def printX():
    threading.Timer(5.0, printX).start()
    print("five")


printX()
while True:
    print("1")
    sleep(1)
```

This works, however I need to be able to dynamically assign what the print statement will be along with the delay.
Desired Code:

```
import threading
from time import sleep


def printX(time, message):
    threading.Timer(int(time), printX).start()
    print(str(message)


printX(time, message)
while True:
    print("Rest of the program continues")
    sleep(1)
```

Thanks for any help in advance :).

Comment: Use the [`args`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) argument:  `threading.Timer(time, printX, args=(time, message)).start()` -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`threading.Timer` could pass arguments with `args`:

```
threading.Timer(int(time), printX, (time, message)).start()
```

read more on [its doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Timer).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method is to define a class with printX as an inner function.

```
class thread:

    def __init__(self, time, message):
        self.time = time
        self.message = message

    def printX(self):
        threading.Timer(int(self.time), self.printX).start()
        print(str(self.message))

thread(3,"test message").printX()

while True:
    print("Rest of the program continues")
    sleep(1)
```